# railstutorial.org - 6.11 - rspec failing, is postgresql the issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I am going through the rails tutorial and am at [section 6.11](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=3.2#code:failing_validates_name_spec)

For some reason, I am getting 4 examples and 4 failures in rspec vs 4 examples and 1 failure (and consequently 0) as in the tutorial.

I am seeing this in my rspec:

```
Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

The thing is, the tutorial is going along in sqlite, but I migrated to postgres (as suggested in the tutorial earlier) so I could learn about postgres as well. Is this what is causing the problems? Shouldn't activerecord be making it transparent as to what kind of database I am using anyways?

I have created the proper databases, updated my database.yml, run a db:mgirate and the command

```
User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
```

works fine in a sandboxed console.

Any help greatly appreciated. I am trying to stay on top of rspec here, to me it is the most challenging part about learning Rails. It almost feels like one spends 90% of one's energy writing and debugging tests instead. (The only stumbling blocks/mind bending headca I've encountered so far have been rspec tests)

The user_rspec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

--

As a secondary question, I find that my rspec tests are running multiple times? I installed the ruby-gntp gem and am finding growl popping up multiple times each time a test is run, with the same information.

[image: rspec multiple times]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

The problem was that the development database was not being migrated to the test database, even when running rake db:migrate, rake db:rollback then migrate, rake db:reset.

The solution was to clone the database:

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same circumstances - migrating from SQLite to PG. After a reinstall of PG - I started getting 20 rspec failures - all around Users. After hours of frustration - one command fixed it all:

**rake db:test:prepare**
or
**bundle exec rake db:test:prepare** (depending on your settings)

[**Ruby Guides - mentions it too** - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

When you do end up destroying your testing database (and it will happen, trust me), you can rebuild it from scratch according to the specs defined in the development database. You can do this by running rake db:test:prepare.